# Is it OK to use the DEC data type in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

The `DEC` type seems to work just fine in PostgreSQL 15:

```
SELECT 12 :: DEC(5,3);
```

producing:

```
 numeric 
---------
  12.000
(1 row)
```

Clearly `DEC` is an alias for the `NUMERIC` type, just like `DECIMAL`. However, when I look at the [data types table in PostgreSQL manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/datatype.html), it doesn't include the `DEC` type. Only `NUMERIC` and `DECIMAL`.

It states above the table:

> Table 8.1 shows all the built-in general-purpose data types. Most of the alternative names listed in the “Aliases” column are the names used internally by PostgreSQL for historical reasons. In addition, **some internally used or deprecated types are available, but are not listed here.**

This makes me wonder whether `DEC` type might be deprecated. I tried to search for deprecated types in PostgreSQL, but didn't manage to find such information.

Is it simply an omission from the documentation? If so, are there perhaps more data type aliases which are supported but not documented?

Or is there something more going on with the `DEC` type?

Comment: DEC (decimal) is an alias for NUMERIC, as you've said.  The parameters for both are identical, so why not just use NUMERIC.

Comment: "*Is it OK to use*" - well if it's not documented I would recommend to avoid it; if you want `NUMERIC` anyway then just write that

Comment: I've been using the `dec` type for decades and have no intention of changing my habits. If it ever gets depreciated, you can always create a domain.

Comment: I would stick with `numeric` or `decimal` as they are documented and it will save somebody down the line from asking this same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dec` is short for `decimal`. Both are aliases for `numeric`.

```sql
test=> SELECT 'dec'::regtype, 'decimal'::regtype, 'numeric'::regtype;
 regtype | regtype | regtype 
---------+---------+---------
 numeric | numeric | numeric
(1 row)
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL)

> The types `decimal` and `numeric` are equivalent. Both types are part of the SQL standard.

I am not sticking out my neck much to claim neither is going to get deprecated. Still, just use the canonical type name `numeric`. No good reason not to.

Comment: Wasn't aware of the `regtype` type, or really any of these special `reg*` types. Useful stuff to know. Much appreciated.